# cmake compiling pcl on centos 6.3 with gcc 6.3.0 fails, assembler reports error

Tags: assembly, cmake, centos, g++, printer-control-language

I am compiling point cloud library on centos 6.3 with gcc 6.3.0 and cmake 3.7. The assembler reports errors as follows:

```
[  2%] Building CXX object common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/src/time_trigger.cpp.o
/tmp/cc7ZJZcC.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc7ZJZcC.s:11887: Error: no such instruction: `shlx %r10,%rax,%r10'
/tmp/cc7ZJZcC.s:45385: Error: no such instruction: `shlx %rbp,%rsi,%rbp'
/tmp/cc7ZJZcC.s:46372: Error: no such instruction: `shlx %rbp,%rsi,%rbp'
make64[2]: *** [common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/src/time_trigger.cpp.o] Error 1
make64[1]: *** [common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/all] Error 2
make64: *** [all] Error 2
```

"which gcc" gives `/usr/bin/gcc` and "gcc --version" gives `gcc (GCC) 6.3.0`. Some posts suggest appending a `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:="-march=haswell"` option after `cmake ..` where 'haswell' is the CPU arch given by `gcc -march=native -Q --help=target | grep march`. But it does not solve the problem. The following steps show my compiling procedure:

```
tar xvf pcl-master.tar.gz
mv pcl-master pcl
cd pcl
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:="-march=haswell"
make
```

And there goes the problem. The `cmake ..` step does show some warnings which I simply ignored as follows:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/pcl_targets.cmake:113 (if):
Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
warning.

Quoted variables like "EIGEN_FOUND" will no longer be dereferenced when the
policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be
used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
common/CMakeLists.txt:7 (PCL_SUBSYS_DEPEND)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/pcl_targets.cmake:113 (if):
Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
warning.

Quoted variables like "FLANN_FOUND" will no longer be dereferenced when the
policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be
used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
kdtree/CMakeLists.txt:7 (PCL_SUBSYS_DEPEND)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/pcl_targets.cmake:113 (if):
Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
warning.

Quoted variables like "FLANN_FOUND" will no longer be dereferenced when the
policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be
used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
search/CMakeLists.txt:7 (PCL_SUBSYS_DEPEND)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/pcl_targets.cmake:113 (if):
Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
warning.

Quoted variables like "VTK_FOUND" will no longer be dereferenced when the
policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be
used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
visualization/CMakeLists.txt:17 (PCL_SUBSYS_DEPEND)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

Anyone knows where the crux of the problem is? Thanks for the help in advance:)

Comment: The CMake warnings are unrelated to your assembler problem. Fix your CMake stuff and clarify your question.

Comment: Tried to fix the cmake stuff using "make distclean" and run ./configure again. didn't help. how to fix cmake? @usr1234567

Comment: use VERBOSE=yes so that you see with that flags the compiler is called

Comment: Neither ./configure nor distclean are CMake. Is there some wrapper involved?

Comment: @usr1234567 how to check if there's any wrapper involved? I am pretty new to this.